# Fixpoint of type exponentiation as a language

Tags: haskell, types, turing-complete

Haskell permits fixpoint of type addition:

```
data Peano = Zero | Succ Peano
```

Haskell also permits fixpoint of type multiplication:

```
data InfBoolList = InfBoolList Bool InfBoolList
```

Yet I was very surprised of that Haskell also permits fixpoint of type exponentiation:

```
newtype FixExp = FixExp {appFixExp :: FixExp -> Bool}
```

The most basic elements of `FixExp`:

```
example1 = FixExp (const False)
example2 = FixExp (const True)
```

`example1` always outputs `False`, `example2` always outputs `True`, regardless of what they were fed.

For another example:

```
example3 = FixExp (`appFixExp` example1)
```

`example3` feeds its operand `example1`. `appFixExp example3 example3` is `appFixExp example3 example1`, which is then `appFixExp example1 example1`, which is then `False`.

For an extreme example:

```
example4 = FixExp (`appFixExp` example4)
```

`example4` is the identity operation. `appFixExp example4 example3` is `appFixExp example3 example4`, which is then `appFixExp example4 example1`, which is then `appFixExp example1 example4`, which is then `False`. And `appFixExp example4 example4` *doesn't halt*!

With help of other functions, some crazy examples include:

```
import Control.Monad

example5 = FixExp (not . `appFixExp` example5)
example6 = FixExp (join appFixExp)
```

So far, `FixExp` seems to be a mini-language. Is `FixExp` Turing-complete?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what your question means. If you combine FixExp with arbitrary Haskell constructs, of course you get a Turing-complete language. You don't even need FixExp for that.

Comment: The standard encoding of the untyped lambda calculus into Haskell (without observations beyond "halts"/"doesn't") goes like `newtype D = D { d :: D -> D }`, and then `[[\x. e]] = D (\x -> [[e]]); [[e1 e2]] = d [[e1]] [[e2]]; [[x]] = x`. If you unwrap the definition of `FixExp` twice, you get `FixExp = FixExp -> Bool = (FixExp -> Bool) -> Bool = Cont Bool FixExp`. If you're able to make an isomorphism between `Cont Bool (FixExp -> FixExp)` and `Cont Bool FixExp` (I haven't been able to yet), then you can use the `D` encoding with some extra `return`s and `>>=`s thrown in.

Comment: Reminds me of Krstic et. al.'s Hyperfunctions: See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=DF55A4AF2AF0C4160D0BDC93D1488B0E?doi=10.1.1.36.2421&rep=rep1&type=pdf and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.36.4961&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: All three recursive definitions are, to some extent, just shorthand for defining an appropriate functor and applying `newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))` to it. For example, `data PeanoF f = ZeroF | SuccF f`, and `type Peano = Fix PeanoF`.